# Rename [life] to [lifestyle]

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

In a [recent question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2855/2072) of mine which asked about the mechanics of life, I was about to use [life](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) until I saw the tag wiki exerpt, which reads:

> Questions tagged with life should be about life in general, not about
>   its mechanics. For example, a question about lifestyle on a particular
>   planet would be a good use of this tag. A question about how a
>   particular planet would affect the cells of a living organism would
>   not fit this tag, the biology tag should be used instead.

I would suggest that, in order to alleviate confusion, this tag should be renamed [lifestyle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle). Doing this would make the tagging system a whole lot more intuitive for people who ask `mechanics of life` questions.

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a good change.

Comment: Follow-up question: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/401/2072

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Remove life tag

I agree that the [life](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) tag should be removed as it is highly ambiguous, and not everyone will read the tag wiki, leading to half a dozen different uses, making the tag meaningless. Your suggestion of renaming it to [lifestyle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle) is a good one, so that the misleading tag name will no longer exist.

## Apply biology tag

Looking at the 7 existing [life](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) questions, all of them are about [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology), and should be retagged as such. The biology tag wiki specifically includes non-Earth-like biology. None of these questions fit the [lifestyle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle) tag.

## Only add lifestyle tag when there are relevant questions

None of the 7 existing questions are about lifestyle, so there is no need for the tag at this point. If you see another question outside these 7 that is about lifestyle, or if you ask a new question about lifestyle, anyone is free to add the tag. If the tag is not applied to questions within a certain period of time, it will be automatically deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure if the tag can be renamed by a mod, or whether it would require setting up a new lifestyle tag and pasting in the existing tag wiki.

Comment: Tags can be renamed by a moderator. However given Beta Decay's comment on the question it looks like that isn't needed at the moment. I personally think the "life" tag should be removed, which I am pretty certain a moderator can do. "lifestyle" sounds like it would come with too great a risk of being borderline [off topic](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/215/29).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling as long as the life tag is gone I'm happy - that all sounds good. I'm happy with lifestyle being abandoned too.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/441/2072

Answer (score 3):

All questions tagged [life](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) have now been retagged to [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology).