# Blacklist the [life] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, specific-tag, tag-blacklist

So, based on [prior discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/396/2072), we've [removed](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/398/2072) all of the [life](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) questions.

Based on that discussion, I changed the tag wiki to say:

> The [community has decided](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/396/2072) that this tag is too ambiguous. Use the
>   tags from the wiki excerpt ( [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) and [lifestyle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle) )
>   instead.

And the wiki exerpt:

> Please do not use this tag -- it is very ambiguous. For questions
>   about lifestyle, use [lifestyle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle). For questions about the
>   mechanics of life, use [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology).

I would suggest [blacklisting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19018/266359) the use of this tag, as [other tags have been blacklisted](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2114/5323) on other sites, because the tag is way too ambiguous and is unproductive, and whatever material may accumulate under it, is covered either by [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) or [lifestyle](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifestyle).

Comment: Prior discussion: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/396/2072

Comment: Personally, I think that culture and lifestyle are the same thing.

Comment: @Vincent Yeah, I was just looking for questions under [tag:lifestyle], didn't find any.....[tag:culture] is probably where it's at. I only mentioned [tag:lifestyle] because someone came up with it as an alternative to [tag:life].

Comment: FYI this is the process for making a tag blacklist request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/152515 - among the details, the tags here should be [discussion] and [blacklist-request].

Comment: @doppelgreener Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [life](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) tag has been removed, so it won't be offered as an option when people start to type a tag name now.  I asked a community manager about blacklisting it, but it's an expensive operation so they reserve that for really *persistent* tags, ones that keep coming back over and over.

Let's try to not need to blacklist the tag.  Please don't use it, and if you see it pop up, please retag with something better.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242624/162102

Comment: I didn't realize that blacklisting tags was so difficult. I saw it done on Mi Yodeya, and thought (incorrectly) that this tag was sufficiently ambiguous to become a lasting problem. Thanks for explaining that.

Comment: @Shokhet I didn't realize how expensive it is, either.  On Mi Yodeya, the tag that was blacklisted was pervasive, bad, and, I strongly suspect, the very first word Jews would come up with if asked "what types of questions belong on a site about Judaism?", so in that case it made sense to do it anyway.  But we've been advised that the blacklist mechanism wasn't really designed for heavy use.  If the "life" tag (or any other on this site) becomes a problem we can certainly revisit.  For now, let's try to just keep it dead using conventional means.