# It's back, the [Life] tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The Life tag was discussed and destroyed before:

[Rename [life] to [lifestyle]](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396/rename-life-to-lifestyle)

[Blacklist the [life] tag](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/401/blacklist-the-life-tag)

However it's come back. Do we still want it gone? Shall we blacklist it or synonym it or what?

It might be too vague to synonym.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a useful tag pretty much anywhere it's used, so, somewhat ironically, I vote to kill it. Or blacklist it, whatever that entails.

Comment: Burninating the tag gets rid of it from all questions but it can be recreated. Blacklisting it needs a CM (mods can't do it) but also prevents the tag being used again. Alternatively if we can pick a synonym that works too (for example biology maybe?)

Comment: The only problem I see with using biology is that I think we also have xenobiology, so life would work for both.

Comment: Yeah, it would probably be a manual retag of anything not biology followed by synonym creation.

Answer (score 4):

**Blacklist**

The reason I propose blacklisting it is that it:

- It is a far too broad a tag, it could be applied to half the questions we have, and [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) already exists when appropriate.
- Given that it has multiple meanings, even making it a synonym might not solve the problem, but probably cause incorrect tagging instead.

There are 37 [life](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/life) questions, 26 of which do not have [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology).

Comment: I agree, and I think that's the conclusion we came to before. I'll give it a bit longer to see what people think but if we see enough upvotes on this I'll get it done.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27882059#27882059